# Save me for later

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> I can be single;
>   I can grind you down;
>   I can hold many words;
>   I can mean up-and-down.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can be single

> single file - a line arranged one behind another

I can grind you down

> file - a tool for grinding

I can hold many words

> a file in computing can hold text

I can mean up-and-down

> a file in chess is an up-and-down column

Title: Save me for later

> file me away, say in a cabinet.